# how to get value from this html date-ranger?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

so i have to get the date values from this date-ranger, but im not sure how this one works. Usually i've seen people using jquery datepickers to get date values, but the code i am working on uses this, which looks to be pure html. i have little experience with html so im confused a little.

here is the line

```
<div class="daterange daterange-inline pull-right" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" 
     data-start-date="2014-12-23" data-end-date="2014-12-30" data-min-date=""
     data-max-date="" style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 2px;"> 
 <i class="entypo-calendar"></i> 
 <span>2014-12-23 - 2014-12-30</span> 
</div>
```

it looks as those its made totally from html and css, and im confused as to how im supposed to get the values from it.

can anyone shed some light on this one? or should i recommend that it be changed to soemthing like a jquery datepicker?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
var dataDate = $(".daterange").attr("data-start-date");

alert(dataDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterange daterange-inline pull-right" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-start-date="2014-12-23" data-end-date="2014-12-30" data-min-date="" data-max-date="" style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 2px;"> <i class="entypo-calendar"></i> <span>2014-12-23 - 2014-12-30</span> </div>
```

or use [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
var dataDate = $(".daterange").data("start-date");

alert(dataDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="daterange daterange-inline pull-right" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-start-date="2014-12-23" data-end-date="2014-12-30" data-min-date="" data-max-date="" style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 2px;"> <i class="entypo-calendar"></i> <span>2014-12-23 - 2014-12-30</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Alex says, this is just HTML, your not going to be able to modify the date, you can retrieve the ranges if you want but i dont think is very useful, i recommend you to use the HTML5 date input:

```
<input type="date" >
```

look at this example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/BMEc9/)

which is using a js library so you can use it cross-browser since it is only supported on Chrome, Safari and Opera. And if you want to learn more about the "standard" about this, learn it here: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dates which are inside the html as data attributes with getAttribute in javascript or with .attr('data-start-date') in jQuery.

javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('daterange')[0].getAttribute('data-start-date'));
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('daterange')[0].getAttribute('data-end-date'));
```

jQuery:

```
alert($('.daterange').attr('data-start-date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no input here, so the user cannot provide any date. My guess is that some external javascript (like jQuery's datepicker) is supposed to transform this. So you need to figure out which scripts are supposed to be loaded on that site.